# Cross domain get ajax request is throwing parsing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.zip-tax.com/request/v20",                    
                data: {
                    key: '1234567890',
                    postalcode: '90265',
                    format: 'json'
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    debugger;
                    // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

When i run above code, it throws me in error block and says

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
[Break On This Error]   

{"version":"v20","rCode":100,"results":[{"geoPostalCode":"902
```

Although it also shows `readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"` and `parsererror`
If i hit that url, i can see the proper json

```
URL: `http://api.zip-tax.com/request/v20?key=1234567890&postalcode=90265&format=json`
Result: `{"version":"v20","rCode":100,"results":[{"geoPostalCode":"90265","geoCity":"MALIBU","geoCounty":"LOS ANGELES","geoState":"CA","taxSales":0.090000003576279,"taxUse":0.090000003576279,"txbService":"N","txbFreight":"N","stateSalesTax":0.064999997615814,"stateUseTax":0.064999997615814,"citySalesTax":0,"cityUseTax":0,"cityTaxCode":"","countySalesTax":0.0099999997764826,"countyUseTax":0.0099999997764826,"countyTaxCode":"19","districtSalesTax":0.014999999664724,"districtUseTax":0.014999999664724},{"geoPostalCode":"90265","geoCity":"PT DUME","geoCounty":"LOS ANGELES","geoState":"CA","taxSales":0.090000003576279,"taxUse":0.090000003576279,"txbService":"N","txbFreight":"N","stateSalesTax":0.064999997615814,"stateUseTax":0.064999997615814,"citySalesTax":0,"cityUseTax":0,"cityTaxCode":"","countySalesTax":0.0099999997764826,"countyUseTax":0.0099999997764826,"countyTaxCode":"19","districtSalesTax":0.014999999664724,"districtUseTax":0.014999999664724},{"geoPostalCode":"90265","geoCity":"TWAIN HARTE","geoCounty":"VENTURA","geoState":"CA","taxSales":0.075000002980232,"taxUse":0.075000002980232,"txbService":"N","txbFreight":"N","stateSalesTax":0.064999997615814,"stateUseTax":0.064999997615814,"citySalesTax":0,"cityUseTax":0,"cityTaxCode":"","countySalesTax":0.0099999997764826,"countyUseTax":0.0099999997764826,"countyTaxCode":"56","districtSalesTax":0,"districtUseTax":0}]}`
```

Please advise. I dont' want to write a server side script.

Comment: That content isn't JSONP. It is regular JSON.

Comment: okie, how to make a correct call? i tried without jsonp also but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how JSONP works.

With proper JSONP, a `<script>` element is placed on the page with the `src` set as the URL you're requesting. This is handled internally by jQuery.

The response of JSONP is **not** JSON. It is JavaScript, calling a function, and passing the JSON as a parameter. That's how cross-domain data transfer is allowed, because you're simply requesting Javascript code.

When making the request, you have to provide the name of the function to be called with the JSON response, usually like:

```
http://www.website.com/request/jsonp?param=value&param2=value2&callback=callbackFunc
```

Therefore, the response would be in the format of:

```
callbackFunc({JSON stuff});
```

jQuery handles this callback stuff internally so that the `success` method ends up being called.

It doesn't look like the API supports JSONP ( http://www.zip-tax.com/documentation ), so you'll have to make an AJAX call to your own server, have that server make the request you need (which returns JSON), and return the JSON in the AJAX response.

Comment: Can't i make direct ajax request to their server and get the result in any case?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Unfortunately no, because it violates the same-origin policy - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript . You could look into CORS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS